# Converting zip file to war file

Tags: java, zip, war, rename

I converted a war file into a zip file to do some customizations. Renaming it shows it as war file but with a zip icon and zip extension in properties. How do one convert a zip file back into a war file?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Judging from the answer and comment below this is more of a [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) Question. Welcome to Stack Overflow though :) Please take a moment to read the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting.

Comment: You converted nothing. You renamed the file, and you didn't renamed back properly. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

my guess is you actually didn't renamed it back to war file. In windows, there is an option to `Hide extensions for known file types`.

If that is checked, you probably just renamed to 
`fileName.war.zip`

Steps to fix in Windows XP -
http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-Hidden-File-Extensions-in-Windows-XP

Steps to fix in Windows 7/Vista -
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/show-or-hide-file-name-extensions

Comment: Yes. I did not rename it properly. Unchecking it and renaming changed it back properly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For windows 10 use this. 
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-file-extensions-in-windows

Answer (score 7):

In windows. You can use the command prompt to rename a file.

```
rename sample.zip sample.war
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of the file from .zip to .war using command prompt.

1.Go to the file location  (cd filelocation)

1. Use below command.

   **Ren file.zip file.war**

Answer (score -1):

1 You can change the name of the file from .zip to .war using command prompt.

use command **mv abc.zip abc.war**